# Open program in foreground from background program

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a small program that's only running in the background (doesn't have any windows). It monitors key presses and when certain requirements are met, it opens specific program. The problem is that the program's window doesn't open in foreground - it opens behind currently active windows. How can I force it to open in the foreground?

I'm using Visual Basic .NET (.NET framework 4.5), this is my current code:

```
Dim temp As New Process
temp = Process.Start("C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe", "-")
temp.WaitForInputIdle(10000)
```

Comment: You'll need to pinvoke SetForegroundWindow().  Getting the window handle you need ought to be pretty challenging.  It also won't work when Windows refuses the request because it has detected that the user is working with another window.  You can't shove a window into the user's face.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this (Its in C#): Taken from [this site](http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/setting-an-application-on-top-other-windows-using-c/).

```
internal class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd,
        int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);

    private const int HWND_TOPMOST = -1;
    private const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Process process = Process.Start(@"notepad.exe", "");

        if (null != process)
        {
            SetWindowPos(process.MainWindowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code does **not** put a window in the foreground.  It merely overlaps the window that the user is using so she can't see anymore what she's typing.

Comment: @HansPassant I did not get you. I know that the program will be seen over all other programs that are mazimized and this can lead to focus being lost from the current program in focus.

Comment: No focus is being lost, regardless of windodw state, this code doesn't change the focus.  Why don't you just try it?

Comment: @HansPassant In my case, I put a sleep before Process.Start, launched the ConsoleApp, brought focus to Firefox, tried searching. During typing, notepad opened and took focus.